# generating git patch from a merge commit ID

Tags: git, merge, patch

I need help in generating a patch from git "merge commit id". I can generate if it was a direct commit id, but not able to do the same with merge commit ID. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

More detail:
I have a merge request which was merged to my source/master git repository with a single merge commit ID, I would like to generate a patch from this merge CommitID.

Note: 
I had a dev branch, their I have made two commits separately these are two different commit ID.
I later raised a merge request, and merged the changes to master repository now this merge has happened correctly but generated a new commitID (merge commitID).

Now I only have reference to this commitID - i need to  generate a patch file with this ID and should generate all the delta from both of my previous commits in the branch.

Comment: Can you show *how* you proceeded (and failed) to generate the patch?

Comment: I am using git format-patch  -m <merge commit ID> 
This is not generating patch specific to all the commits which has happen under merge commit ID,  Instead it is generating patch in the last commit happened in that branch